# No visible @interface 'UIView' declares the selector 'loadRequest'

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiwebview

I am creating a webView application by following [this](http://conecode.com/news/2011/05/ios-tutorial-creating-a-web-view-uiwebview/) tutorial. I followed all the steps exactly but got this error:

```
No visible @interface 'UIView' declares the selector 'loadRequest'
```

-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   NSString *fullURL = @"http://google.com/";
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
   NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];

   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

How can i fix it ?

Comment: have you taken _viewWeb as UIView object ??? please check it my friend..you will have to create object of UIWebview.

Comment: in step 15, you should confirm the viewWeb is UIWebView not UIView

Comment: show your declaration part for _viewWeb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @NiravPatel, @Chancy. I did this mistake in step 15.

I was using

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewWeb;
```

instead of

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *viewWeb;
```